# ReactiveUI - Proper way to implement the ReactiveCommand

Tags: c#, blazor, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I'm experimenting ReactiveI on blazor client-side c# .Net5.  I'm using a reactive command to invoke a method which take an integer as an argument and returns a `Student` object. The need is, whenever the command is invoked it should update the `Student` property on the ViewModel by calling `ToProperty()`

But, getting a compilation error here. I'm new to ReactiveUI, and what is missing here and what is the proper way to implement the requirement?

According to the ReactiveUI documentation:

> `ReactiveCommand<TInput, TOutput>` adds the concept of Input and
> Output generic types. The Input is often passed in by the View and
> it's type is captured as `TInput`, and the Output is the result of
> executing the command which type is captured as `TOutput`.

Code:

```
public class StudentViewModel : ReactiveObject
{

    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<Student> _student;

    public Student Student => _student.Value;

    public ReactiveCommand<int, Student> GetCommand { get; }

    public StudentViewModel()
    {
        GetCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<int>(GetStudent);
        _student = GetCommand.ToProperty(this, x => x.Student, scheduler: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);
    }

    private async Task<Student> GetStudent(int id)
    {
        //Mock - Fetches the Student record from Server
        return await Task.FromResult(new Student());
    }
}
```

> Compiler Error:
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type '`ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommand<int, System.Reactive.Unit>`' to '`ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommand<int, Student>`'

Comment: Try using the two generic version of CreateFromTask

Comment: Eg `CreateFromTask<int, Student>(`

Comment: @GlennWatson It worked! I couldn't find such example anywhere. Thanks!